# Lagrange Polynomial Interpolation - Equation Help

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I understand the concept of Lagrange Interpolation but am having issues understanding how to interpret the following general equation (which I will be provided) for n points. For example, how would you get the equation for n = 4 points from the general equation below?

Thanks!

[image: Lagrange Polynomial]

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have to put $n=4$ in those formulas. You will get $4$ terms for $p(x)$. Also you will have $3$ terms in the numerator of each $L_k$ (for $k=1..4$) and $3$ terms in the denominator.

Comment: how do you reach the following for 3 points based on the general equation? http://imgur.com/44g7aTy

Comment: That image is the equation for $n=3$. You can get the formula by writing out explicitly $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$ and then replacing them in the expression for $p(x)$.

Comment: I do understand the idea of substituting the values but I can't reach the specific equation based on the general equation for n=3 or beyond.

Comment: When I sub in the k value I get more terms than I should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ be mutually distinct numbers and we need to fit the polynomial of degree 3 passing through $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),(x_4,y_4)$. Then 
$$p(x)=L_1(x)y_1+L_2(x)y_2+L_3(x)y_3+L_4(x)y_4,$$
where 
$$L_1(x)=\frac{(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)(x_1-x_4)},$$ 
$$L_2(x)=\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)}{(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)(x_2-x_4)},$$
$$L_3(x)=\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_4)}{(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)(x_3-x_4)},$$ 
$$L_4(x)=\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_4-x_1)(x_4-x_2)(x_4-x_3)}.$$